# Why to use CAssetManager?

Tags: javascript, yii, assets

This question is about Yii Framework class [`CAssetManager`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager/) but might be asked in general as well.

What are the reasons behind using `CAssetManager` (or similar techniques) for publishing Javascript and other files (kept in protected directory) to web-accessible directory, instead of directly putting them to web-accessible directory and directly linking them to layout / HTML file with `<script>`.

Yii documentation doesn't come with anything specific. It just explains, how `CAssetManager` works, but doesn't say anything about, why we should use it.

The only reason, that I come with, is that with `CAssetsManager` you can publish JS, CSS and other files when you really need them. Only in selected views. Directly linking them to layout file makes them registered in every view, that uses particular layout.

Is that correct? Are there any other reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in two words. For example, you have your custom widget placed at protected/widgets folder. It has its own styles and js files that should be included only when that widget is rendered. But that files are located in subfolder of the widget (for example protected/widgets/your_widget/assets/css/widget.css) and that file is not accessible from web, because it is at protected folder. So inside your widget class (usually at init() method) you should publish that folder via CAssetManager:

```
$this->assetsUrl = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.widgets.your_widget.assets'));
```

Now you can register your widget css file like this

```
Yii::app()->registerCssFile($this->assetsUrl . '/css/widget.css);
```

For more details read http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets

Comment: Your answer is briefly supporting, what I figured out myself. But I'm accepting it as the only one available! :]